# How to modify this variable?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, callback

Take this example:

```
var data = "foo";
db.collection('users').find({}).toArray(function(err,docs){ // a mongodb object
  data = 'bar';
});
console.log(data); // prints 'foo'
```

How can I make it print 'bar', aka how do I change the value of `data` within the callback?

Comment: It's all about async...

Comment: Ask yourself two questions, `1` is it invoked, `2` when is it invoked (i.e. async?)

Comment: It seems that you have already changed the value within the callback. The function is asynchronous, since there won't be any change right after the function execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have implied, your question is not that of scope, but that of the order of execution. Your console.log is called before 'bar' is assigned to value.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get used to think asynchronously! The value will only change when the callback is executed.

Do it like this:

```
var data = "foo";
db.collection('users').find({}).toArray(function(err,docs){ // a mongodb object
  data = 'bar';
  console.log(data);
});
```